# Forms in AngularJS 6

Tags: angular, forms

I had a problem on submit a form that is doesn't hire, and I already put FormsModule in app.module.ts

This is a component and a simple HTML form:.

```js
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-products',
  templateUrl: './products.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./products.component.css']
})
export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {
  productName = 'A book';
  products = ['A book', 'A tree'];
  isDisabled = true;

  constructor() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.isDisabled = false;
    }, 3000);
  }

  onAddProduct(form) {
    // this.products.push(this.productName);
    console.log(form);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

```html
<h1>My products</h1>
<form (ngSubmit)="onAddProduct(f)" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
  <input type="text" ngModel name="productName" required>
  <button type="submit">Change Text</button>
</form>
<div *ngFor="let product of products">{{ product }}</div>
```

This is a module that I already put the FormsModule

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ProductComponent } from './product/product.component';
import { ProductsComponent } from './products/products.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ProductComponent,
    ProductsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

When I click the button that happens nothing.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue above is that you need to pass the form f not t

change it as,

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onAddProduct(f)" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
```

and you can access inside the method as,

```
  onAddProduct(form) {
    if (form.valid) {
    console.log(form.value.productName);
    }
  }
```

**[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tlbpn1)**

Comment: Thank you for your help, but still not working. This my typo error in the post for the 'f'.

Comment: I did, but I don't know why in my environment doesn't work. This is a simple project to ask in a post and in another project the same problem. is there something wrong with installing angular.

Comment: you might be making silly mistake, just compare the demo with your code

Comment: It's working, Thank you. I changed the browser I don't know why Chrome doesn't print the result.